# $A\subset[0,1]$ with measure $<1$ so that $\int_A f(x) dx = \int_{[0,1]} f(x) dx$ for continuous $f$?

Tags: measure-theory, integration

Is there a set $A\subset[0,1]$ of measure $<1$ so that $\int_A f(x) dx = \int_{[0,1]} f(x) dx$ for continuous $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$?

$A^c$ must have empty interior for sure. (Otherwise support $f$ on the interior to get a contradiction to the above)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there does not. Hint: Try $f=1$.